# changing mingw' startup directory or creating mingw symlinks

Tags: windows, mingw

What's the easiest way to set mingw's console startup directory? I only use mingw for compiling. but due to the lack of editors or even symlinks I am confused how to tell mingw console to come up in a different directory rather than regular home dir.

It would also be helpful if someone knows how to place "real" symlinks to ntfs drives like cygwin can do. mingw copies the content and that is useless when working on a subversion dir.

I am a lazy guy, and i find it painful to do the cd /c/Documents/USER/.../Project all the time :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mount points instead of symlinks. mingw doesn't support ntfs symlinks (they're rather new anyway), but mount points are okay for most use cases (such as simple access to the directory you're working in outside mingw).

And the easiest way to set a new default directory is probably using a `.bashrc` in the home directory that `cd`s to the desired directory.

Comment: .bashrc is ignored, mingw only comes with /bin/sh  (no bash)

Comment: for mountpoints to desktop or so one have to to en entry in c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab

C:\DOKUME~1\<USER>\Desktop /home/<USER>/desktop    (on german install)

Comment: Thanks for the correction (re .bashrc) and addition (re fstab).

I have some significant parts of msys around, including bash, somewhat assuming that it's part of mingw. `/etc/profile` should work with the stock sh, too.

Answer (score 24):

If anyone else finds this post looking for an answer, what worked for me was

1. Create shortcut if one doesn't already exist. Could be on your desktop or taskbar.
2. **Right click** >> **Properties** >> and change the **Start in:** value.
3. Use the shortcut and instantly start in your project directory.

I have several shortcuts for various projects in a line on my Desktop so I can quickly start a terminal in each of those directories and get right to work!

Comment: I've done this for the git-bash shell and it seems to work for that.

Comment: Great tip, but this only worked for me when I commented out `cd $HOME` in "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\profile". `cd $HOME` is the last non-comment line in "profile". For more information [see this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/607413/start-msys-in-current-folder)

Comment: This works, of course, but in my case I also had to remove the `--cd-to-home` parameter from the `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home` in the "Target" field of my git-bash shortcut.

Answer (score 9):

this is the simplest way, I think:

- open the shell
- vim .profile (ESC / i to enter insert mode)

  #!/bin/bash

  cd /c/Users/jbr

(ESC / wq to write and close editor)

- test the .profile bash file: source .profile
- close and reopen the shell.

Enjoy,
Fabar

Comment: You don't have to `source` the file if you're going to close and reopen the shell, but it certainly won't hurt.

Comment: like this solution

Answer (score 4):

I found the following solution, I didn't want mountpoints, I wanted explicitly the possibility to start from any directory where I am currently (working dir) so I made a bunch of scripts.

They works, but still have issues with path containing spaces (I'm sorry):

#### bash.bat

Place it in your path so that you can run it from cmd.exe

```
@echo off

set STARTUP_DIR=%CD%

D:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\bash.exe --login
```

**Ensure you have an environment variable set called HOME which points to what you want as home user directory (must be without spaces!!) in my case D:\Users\Myname

#### .bashrc

Place it in your home directory

```
if [[ "$STARTUP_DIR" != "$PWD" ]]; then
  cd $STARTUP_DIR
fi
```

Now, considering bash.exe will run **.bash_profile** and not .bashrc, I added this, in the home directory:

#### .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

I use Console2 so I can just set as startup shell my bash.bat file and that's all I need.

Answer (score 4):

By default when I start `{install location of MinGW}\msys\1.0\msys.bat` the shell is started in the folder `{install location of MinGW}\msys\1.0\home\jbr`.

[image: MinGW screenshot before]

I created a file `{install location of MinGW}\msys\1.0\home\jbr\.profile` containing this:

```
# Cd to my windows home:
cd /c/Users/jbr
```

Now when I open a new shell `msys.bat`; I am at the correct location:

[image: MinGW screenshot after]

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I edited `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\profile` and changed line 32 from:

```
# Set up USER's home directory
if [ -z "$HOME" ]; then
  HOME="/home/$LOGNAME"
fi
```

to:

```
  HOME="/c/Users/$LOGNAME"
```

And now when I open MinGW (msys) it uses the default Windows home folder. This enables functionality such as `~/.profile`, `~/.ssh` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

> It would also be helpful if someone knows how to place "real" symlinks to ntfs drives like cygwin can do. mingw copies the content and that is useless when working on a subversion dir.

Cygwin does not place real symlinks.